# Is there a way to run all the arguments from a function and save them in the environment? (Purpose: help debug a function)

Tags: r

When I create custom functions, I sometimes need to run it line by line to find the source of an error.

Is there a way to run in one line of code all the arguments in the function?

For example, let's say I have the following custom function:

```
myfun <- function(x, y, z = 3, message = c("testing","with","y=")) {
cat(paste(message, collapse = " "), y, "\n")
if(x<2) x <- as.character(x)
res <- x+y-z
return(res)
}

# This works
myfun(3,1)

# This does not work
myfun(1,3)
```

In order to find the source of my error, I want to run line by line my function.
Before doing that, I need to save in my environment x and y, and do:

```
# Assign the arguments
x = 1
y = 3
z = 3
message = c("testing","with","y=")

# Go line by line in the function and realise that the issue is with the as.character() transformation
message(paste(message, collapse = " "), y)) # This works
if(x<2) x <- as.character(x) # This works
res <- x+y-z # This does not
```

Ideally, I am looking for something that would do the same as if I did:

```
x = 3; y = 1; z = 3; message = c("testing","with","y=")
```

`eval(formals(myfun))` allows me to see all the arguments in the function, and those with pre-defined values, but it does not "create" them in my environment nor does it show the values I chose.

I cannot just do a find+replace "," by ";" because in my example, I have some arguments that are vectors or lists (e.g., `message = c("testing","with","y=")` cannot become `message = c("testing";"with";"y=")` .

Any idea? I will be working on this when I have time and will post an answer if I find a solution.

Comment: Isn't it more direct (and more reproducible) to just `debug(myfun)` then call it as needed?

Comment: One (of perhaps a few?) difference with using `debug(myfun)` and calling it vice setting the formals as variables in the current environment is that `missing(x)` will work in the former and not in the latter (errs with `'missing' can only be used for arguments`). Others: if this is defined with a package, then depending on how you load it, non-exported functions in that package might not be visible on the console whereas within `debug(..)` they will be visible without `:::`-extraction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I never use debug but have seen it in many tutorials.
I am not sure it does all I want to do because it does not return at every step the object I am creating. For example, when I reshape a data frame within the function, I like to make sure it did exactly what I wanted to do (it does not only need to run, it needs to run properly).
I could still use a way to do what I said, but I will try debug() next time!

Comment: _"not return at every step"_, nope, not correct. You can step through each and every line ... or you can run arbitrary code (whether or not it is exactly as written in the function. Since you're working primarily in a debugging mode to troubleshoot, when I'm doing that I often figure out what I need and then just `Q`uit the debugger immediately (returning R to the regular console) without `c`ontinuing within the function, so that I can re-`source` the function and try again without the `debug`ger. I highly suggest you learn to use it, since it appears your assumptions are not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works best for me, but see also the answer by Nir Graham.

Steps are to pass the arguments in a list (copy-paste in my case), then use the function `list2env` in base R.

```
arguments <- list(x, y, z = 3, message = c("testing","with","y="))
list2env(arguments, 
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use save, to store the entry values of your function and the load them to play with your function interactively. Like so :

```
myfun <- function(x, y, z = 3, message = c("testing","with","y=")) {
  save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = "myfun.RData")
  cat(paste(message, collapse = " "), y, "\n")
  if(x<2) x <- as.character(x)
  res <- x+y-z
  return(res)
}

# This works
myfun(3,1)

base::load("myfun.Rdata")
```